# UITest breaking when using Picker View

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, uitest

I'm trying to change the value of a picker view within a UITest. All other pickers are behaving as expected except for one picker that has the values: ["standard", "anniversary", "bike", ... ].

When I call the following like on the test:

```
    app.pickerWheels["standard"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "bike")
```

I get the following error:

Internal error: unable to find current value 'standard' in possible values  for the picker wheel "standard" PickerWheel